# Where can I find individual-level name and street address data?

Tags: us-census, address, names

I'm looking for, more or less, phone book type data, including full name, street addresses, and sex for the purpose of generating simulated data for research. This seems like it would be easy to find, but I'm having trouble locating, e.g. historical census *transcripts*.

Am I missing where to find this data through the US Census? Are there other sources of this sort of information? The data does not need to be current (historical records are ok).

Comment: Have you tried https://www.archives.gov/research/census ?